# How do i get remaining seconds of future date in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, datetime

So i have an API, which gives me date format like this `11/21/2022 19:00:00` what i need to do is i have to schedule notification for this datetime, but the problem is i am using `react-native/expo` which accepts the scheduling time in seconds.

How do i convert this datetime to seconds, i mean if today's date is `11/15/2022 12:00:00` and the date on which the notification should be scheduled is `11/16/2022 12:00:00` which means the future date in 1 day ahead of todays date, and 1 day is equal to `86400` seconds, which means i have to trigger notification after `86400` seconds. So how do i get the remaining seconds of the upcoming date?

Comment: Look for [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference)

Comment: Thanks, but its giving me output in - (minus) i don't know why, ``` const d1 = dayjs("2022-11-15 13:00")
const d2 = dayjs("2022-11-16 12:00")

const res = d1.diff(d2)

console.log(res / 1000)```

Comment: Just reverse the dates! That is `[recent date].diff([old date])`... The same order as this hypothethic math operation `[recent date] - [old date]`.

Comment: Your issue is parsing an unsupported format, where parsing is implementation dependent. Write a parse function (maybe 3 lines of code) or use a library but remember to **always** supply the input format. Otherwise it will likely fall back to the built–in parser and you're back where you started.

Answer (score 3):

### Use .getTime()

- function [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns number of milliseconds since start of epoch (1/1/1970)
- get the number of milliseconds and divide it 1000 to seconds
- subtract (round) and you have the difference

according to [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) is only [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of [ECMA262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) string supported, so use:

- `new Date("2022-11-16T12:00:00Z")`
- or `new Date(2022,10,16,12)`
- rather not `n̶e̶w̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶e̶(̶"̶1̶1̶/̶2̶1̶/̶2̶0̶2̶2̶ ̶1̶9̶:̶0̶0̶:̶0̶0̶"̶)̶` that can lead to unexpected behaviour

```js
const secondsInTheFuture = new Date("2022-11-16T12:00:00Z").getTime() / 1000;
const secondsNow = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
const difference = Math.round(secondsInTheFuture - secondsNow);

console.log({ secondsInTheFuture, secondsNow, difference });
```

Comment: Using the built–in parser for unsupported formats is not recommended. The difference between a date and now in seconds can be `(new Date(2022,10,16,12) - Date.now()) / 1e3`. ;-)

Comment: ISO 8601 Is not the only format supported by ECMA-262. It also supports the formats produced by *Date.prototype.toString* and *toUTCString*. See [*ECMA-262::Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-date.parse)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the epoch time in js with the function **+ new Date**, if you are passing any date value, to **new Date(dateValue)**, please make sure to stringify.

```
+ new Date
```

To get the diff b/w these two dates in seconds,

```
const initialDate = '11/15/2022 12:00:00'
const futureDate = '11/16/2022 12:00:00'
const diffInSeconds = (+ new Date(futureDate) - + new Date(initialDate)) / 1000
```

ps: epoch time is in milliseconds, hence dividing by 1000.

Comment: You can get the "epoch time" with *Date.now()* and avoid creation of a redundant *Date* object, so `(new Date(futureDate) - Date.now()) / 1e3`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved using dayjs package**

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs")

const d1 = dayjs("2022-11-15 13:00")
const d2 = dayjs("2022-11-16 12:00")

const res = d1.diff(d2) / 1000 // ÷ by 1000 to get output in seconds

console.log(res)
```